# Батник или PowerShell скрипт на перемещение файлов

Tags: cmd, администрирование, powershell

Допустим, имеется директория с произвольной вложенностью и в этих директориях на разных уровнях лежат файлы.

Задача:

Взять абсолютно все файлы, которые находятся на разных уровнях и перенести их в одно место.

Хотелось бы увидеть, как это делается классическим батником(Если такое возможно) и PowerShell'ом.

Comment: Если никто не отпишется - могу рассказать как это делается на линуксе.

Answer (score 7):

Происходит копирование всех файлов из всех подкаталогов каталога `SourcePath` в `DestPath` (файлы сваливаются в кучу). Имена у файлов должны быть уникальными, иначе часть их потеряется.

Обычный батник:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b SourcePath') do copy /y %%~fi DestPath
```

Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem SourcePath -Recurse -File | Copy-Item -Dest DestPath
```

Ну и для линукса:

```
find SourcePath -type f -exec cp '{}' DestPath \;
```